# Wordpress very strange 404 error with email at end of Url

Tags: wordpress

For my site under wordpress i am having a very wired issue with 404 warning appearing from Google (GWT) and my 404 plugin.

**I get hundred of 404 like :** /article-name​/email@website.com

I checked everywhere the email doesnt appear on the site and i checked database, those links are nowhere to be found.

Also i removed my email from everywhere on the site and it doesnt help gogle still think those are broken links on my site.

Would you have an idea of how to fix this ?

thx u !

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem today and was able to solve it.

Here is my solution:

The root cause for my problem, (likely this one as well) is that I did some social media linking via the theme I installed. There are Facebook page etc, and there is **Email**.

When rendered

```
<li class="facebook">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/your.page" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

And for the email icon, it is the following:

```
<li class="mail">
 <a href="email@website.com" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
 </a>
</li>
```

when you click on this `<a>` tag, it will point to `/article-name​/email@website.com` because it is interpreted as a **relative url**, whereas the Facebook link is an absolute url since it has `https://`

**To Fix This**

**use `mailto:email@website.com` instead of `email@website.com` for your email address.**

The theme probably should wrote `a href="mailto:{{email}}"` in their template. But if they didn't, you should write `mailto:` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, There is some additional script added in your wordpress file. try to remove header.php, footer.php one by one and see error comes or not. If error doesn't come then check your code in these files. I am sure there is some script added in any file.

Comment: Hello Arashad,i checked as well nothing into header / footer or any file.

Answer (score 0):

Resave your permalink settings, that should sort it out, but information can only get appended to urls via the `.access` file, which is set in the permalinks section. I'd check that if I was you.

Comment: Hello Gavin, i checked it's not the .httaccess creation those error.

Comment: Ok then,... as you say ....strange. Open your sitemap.xml in an editor and check the links there.  Maybe there is a problem within your sitemap generator, assuming you are using one. I must tell you that in my GWT for various sites I also tend to see a number of 'so called' errors, so I have learned to ignore them.

Comment: i also checked the sitemap and cannot find anything wrong in it ;(

Comment: Well half the problem with GMT is it takes so long for any changes to reflect, so it's even possible your attemps to fix things have worked :(. However, perhaps it's just best to email Google support and ask them about your problem.